# Django data hierarchy question

Tags: python, django

I am new to Django and I am trying to build a data hierarchy that follows this pattern:

There will be several Communities - say `Huntsville`, `Phoenix`, and `Madison`.

Each of those communities will be able to have several distinct `Categories`. For example, `Huntsville` may have `Hunting`, `fishing`, and `skiing` - and `Phoenix` may have running, `biking`, and `swimming`.  Then each of the particular categories will have a number of distinct detail views.  I tried to make this happen with:

```
from django.db import models

class Community(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200) #arbitrary max length

class Category(models.Model):
    community = models.ForeignKey(Community)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=200) #arbitrary max length

class Detail_View(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
    detailView = models.CharField(max_length=200) #arbitrary max length
    website = models.CharField(max_length=200) #arbitrary max length
```

but it doesn't really seem to be working the correctly and I can't quite figure out why.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure I fully understand the behavior you're looking for, but I have some advice anyway.

First, it looks like you're implementing a one-to-many when you really want a many-to-many.

Check out http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/models/relations/

Per that link, use `models.ManyToManyField` instead of `models.ForeignKey`

Also if you meant to define this as a one-to-many, you probably don't want `Category` to reference `Community`.  Use the phrase "has a" or "has many" to determine this.  Since a `Community` "has a" `Category`, the `ForeignKey` (or `ManyToManyField`) should be defined on the `Community` model, not the `Category` one.

I'd strongly recommend taking a look at the freely available [Django Book](http://www.djangobook.com/) project, especially the chapter on [Advanced Models](http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter10/)

Hope this helps!